# Apply Image Manipulations to an image to make a new image

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript, image-manipulation

I am working on an Image manipulation application which will be developed using Flash/ C#.Net. Is this possible to save the image manipulations (not the image) saved from Adobe Lightroom for a specific image & then merge these change sets with an image to make a new image using C#.Net?

Also, the application for image manipulation will be developed in the Flash/ Action Script. Please share some links as to how we can save the image manipulations for an image (not the image) so that it can be merged with an image later on.

Kindly suggest some links.

Comment: i want to make a fake image by applying copy_move forgery in python, can you give me some ideas about it?, im a new to programming

Answer (score 0):

Just store a list of commands e.g.

```
1 -> rotate on 90 degree
2 -> move 10px. left
....
```

Comment: Eugeny - Isn't it too complex while merging this changeset with original image ?

Comment: @AnilC,hm! Maybe you should try to merge changes, or at least some part of changelist. E.g. `move 10px. left` and `move 10px. up` and then `rotate on 90 degree` can be written as one linear transformation.

Comment: Is there any specific format for generating changesets so that it can be applied to images in c#.net?